# Railsのルーティングの書き方で理解できてないところがある

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Railsのルーティングを見ていて、わからない記述があったので質問させてください。
これは/sample（や/sample/hoge）に遷移した時にsample#showを見に行くという理解で良いでしょうか？

```
resource :sample, controller: :sample, only: [:show] do
  get '*other', to: 'sample#show'
end
```

ちなみにこのsample#showはSPAのファイルを読みに行っており

```
def show
  render file: Rails.public_path.join('dist', 'web', 'sample', 'index.html'), layout: false
end
```

のように書かれています。
SPA側には

/sample
/sample/confirm
/sample/complete
に相当する画面のファイルがあります。

Answer (score 0):

`get '*other', to: 'sample#show'` の部分については、ルーティンググロブが使われています。`sample/なんとかかんとか` を get しようとしたときに `sample#show` にルーティングします。このとき「なんとかかんとか」の部分が `params[:other]` に入ります。

[https://railsguides.jp/routing.html#ルーティンググロブとワイルドカードセグメント](https://railsguides.jp/routing.html#%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B0%E3%82%B0%E3%83%AD%E3%83%96%E3%81%A8%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%83%89%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89%E3%82%BB%E3%82%B0%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88)

> ルーティンググロブ (route globbing) とはワイルドカード展開のことであり、ルーティングのある位置から下のすべての部分に特定のパラメータをマッチさせる際に使います。例:
>
> ```rb
> get 'photos/*other', to: 'photos#unknown'
> ```